# Unable to start mongod process on redhat

Tags: mongodb

I try to start mongod process from /etc/init.d folder with command `mongod`,but I get the following error :

```
2016-11-14T16:26:55.264+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=16092 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=xyz
2016-11-14T16:26:55.264+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.12
2016-11-14T16:26:55.264+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 33934938e0e95d534cebbaff656cde916b9c3573
2016-11-14T16:26:55.264+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-93-197-138 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2016-11-14T16:26:55.264+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-11-14T16:26:55.264+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-11-14T16:26:55.289+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2016-11-14T16:26:55.289+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

The above error says that it is unable to find dbpath, but mongod script file should pick configuration from /etc/mongod.conf file where I have mentioned the dbpath, Here I am putting some contents from mongod script file by which we come to know that  it is suppose to pick the configuration from /etc/mongod.conf file :

```
#!/bin/bash
# mongod - Startup script for mongod
# chkconfig: 35 85 15
# description: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
# processname: mongod
# config: /etc/mongod.conf
# pidfile: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
 . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
# things from mongod.conf get there by mongod reading it
# NOTE: if you change any OPTIONS here, you get what you pay for:
# this script assumes all options are in the config file.
CONFIGFILE="/etc/mongod.conf"
OPTIONS=" -f $CONFIGFILE"
SYSCONFIG="/etc/sysconfig/mongod"
```

And Here are some contetns from mongod.conf file :

```
# mongod.conf
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: false
#  engine:
    mmapv1:
     smallFiles: true
#  wiredTiger:
```

I am able to start mongod process by specifying --dbpath option in command itself as follows :

```
 mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo
```

But I want know the reason, why it is not picking the dbpath from /etc/mongod.conf file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the config file using `--config` so that mongod.exe can use the config file to start the server.

syntax:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Reference:

1. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file